# maven is it possible to execute one goal of plugin to the parent only, and another to all the children?

Tags: maven

Multiple `<plugin>` elements are not allowed and as I understand `<inherited>false</inherited>` could be only set as plugin configuration, not as goal configuration.

Comment: What kind of plugin are we talking about and what kind of things is only needed for parent only cause a parent has no code?

Comment: I want to execute a custom plugin that parses a file that is located in the parent directory. Then set properties to the project (these properties should inherited by the children). This is the first goal.

For the second goal, which I want to be executed on all the children, I need the properties that will be set in the first goal.

Comment: First never have code in parent which is of packaging pom which means no code. Furthermore the question is: What kind of properties? What purpose do those properties have? And what kind of problem are you trying to solve with those properties / plugin?